# Como configurar Nginx para nodejs e php?

Tags: php, wordpress, node.js

Estou aqui tentando configurar um servidor básico na digitalocean, onde eu queria que ao acessar meudominio.com ele redirecione para o programa em nodejs+express rodando na porta 3000 e ao acessar meudominio.com/blog redirecione para o /var/www/blog onde tem um blog feito em wordpress..

Alguem pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta como está seu arquivo de configuração do nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Melhor você usar subdomínios, manda o DNS apontar para seu servidor e usa ngnix como proxy.

Eu já usei assim:

- site1.com -> Node rodando local -> //127.0.0.1:4000
- site2.com -> Node rodando local -> //127.0.0.1:5000

No arquivo **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site1**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site1.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
    }
}
```

No arquivo **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site2**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site2.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }
}
```

No caso você só teria que usar, **site.com**, e **blog.site.com** ;)